# Variance estimates of Grand Mean and Treatment Effect in ANOVA

Tags: mathematical-statistics, anova

Suppose a random sample of size $n_i$ is taken from $i = 1,2,...k$ and $k$ is the number of populations to be compared, the ANOVA Model is given by $Y_{ij} = \mu +\tau_i + \epsilon_{ij}$. I would like to ask on how to prove the following regarding the variance of the estimator $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\tau_i$ for ANOVA:

$Var(\hat\mu) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$

$Var(\hat\tau_i) = \frac{(r-1)\sigma^2}{n}$

where $\tau_i = \mu_i - \mu$, $\sum n_i\tau_i = 0$ and $\epsilon_{ij}$ is independently and normally distributed with parameters $(0, \sigma^2)$

Comment: Where does $\sigma^2$ come from?

Comment: @a_statistician Apologies for missing that out, I have just included that information in.  $\sigma^2$ comes from the distribution of the error terms

Comment: Suppose $k = 2, \mu = 0, \mu_1 =\tau_1 = -1, \mu_2 = \tau_2 = 1, n_1 = 10, n_2 = 20$, then $\sum n_i\tau_i = 10$. So $\sum n_i\tau_i = 0$ is not true. And this situation is not included in your model?